# Should I use 'a' or 'any' in the sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Should I use "a" or "any" in this sentence?

> The Nationalist Party has won 25 seats so far. No other party has been able to win **a/any** seat after several rounds of counting.

Answer (score 3):

- "No other party has been able to win **a seat**"

Here, the word "seat" is singular, so we use "a seat". The other parties have not been able to win a single seat, let alone more than one.

You could also write it like this, however:

- "No other party has been able to win **any seats**"

Here, we are referring to the seats as a whole. (No party has been able to win any amount of seats.) This has the same meaning.